# Is the order of publication in a "multiple" call guaranteed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mqtt, paho

I would like to publish a set (~100) of messages at once to an MQTT broker. To do so I will use [`publish.multiple()`](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/docs/index.php#multiple).

The messages are of the form `topic/one`, `topic/two`, ... with each a payload. The order for these messages does not matter.

I need, however, to send first a message to `topic` with an empty payload in order to delete the existing messages. I would like to place it first in the list of messages to be sent.

Is there a guarantee that it will be processed first?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [paho publish code](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/src/paho/mqtt/publish.py), it invokes Collections.popleft() so if you pass a tuple that has the no-op payload first, I believe it should work.